# Merge maps by key

Tags: scala, functional-programming, maps, scalaz

Say I have two maps:

```
val a = Map(1 -> "one", 2 -> "two", 3 -> "three")
val b = Map(1 -> "un", 2 -> "deux", 3 -> "trois")
```

I want to merge these maps by key, applying some function to collect the values (in this particular case I want to collect them into a seq, giving:

```
val c = Map(1 -> Seq("one", "un"), 2 -> Seq("two", "deux"), 3 -> Seq("three", "trois"))
```

It feels like there should be a nice, idiomatic way of doing this.

Comment: You should include the information, how to handle elements which happen to exist only in one Map, preferably in the example data for easy testing, to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[`scala.collection.immutable.IntMap`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/IntMap.html) has an `intersectionWith` method that does precisely what you want (I believe):

```
import scala.collection.immutable.IntMap

val a = IntMap(1 -> "one", 2 -> "two", 3 -> "three", 4 -> "four")
val b = IntMap(1 -> "un", 2 -> "deux", 3 -> "trois")

val merged = a.intersectionWith(b, (_, av, bv: String) => Seq(av, bv))
```

This gives you `IntMap(1 -> List(one, un), 2 -> List(two, deux), 3 -> List(three, trois))`. Note that it correctly ignores the key that only occurs in `a`.

As a side note: I've often found myself wanting the `unionWith`, `intersectionWith`, etc. functions from [Haskell's `Data.Map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/0.4.2.0/doc/html/Data-Map.html) in Scala. I don't think there's any principled reason that they should only be available on `IntMap`, instead of in the base `collection.Map` trait.

Comment: unionWith, interesectionWith etc look exactly like what I'm looking for. Just a shame they're in the wrong language!

Comment: I just tested the scalaz functionality `intersectionWith` and found out, that keys which occur in b are ignored as well as in a.

Comment: what if keys are of type String? or any other type?

Comment: @mpr Then you'll need to do something like map over the values with `List(_)` and sum with the monoid instance for maps in Scalaz or Cats (or of course just write your own `intersectionWith` from scratch).

Answer (score 23):

```
val a = Map(1 -> "one", 2 -> "two", 3 -> "three")
val b = Map(1 -> "un", 2 -> "deux", 3 -> "trois")

val c = a.toList ++ b.toList
val d = c.groupBy(_._1).map{case(k, v) => k -> v.map(_._2).toSeq}
//res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Seq[java.lang.String]] =
        //Map((2,List(two, deux)), (1,List(one, un), (3,List(three, trois)))
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining that _._1 for a complete scala newbie ?

Comment: A map is collection of Tuples2. For example:
val tuple: Tuple3[Int, Int, String] = (100, 10, "one") ,
if you want get a string "one" you can use tuple._3 . Tuples are useful e.g. if you want return more than one value

Comment: And the first part of `_._1` (underscore before dot) is an anonymous name of argument. For example: `List(1,2,3,4).map(_.toDouble)` will cast all of the list members to Double. It is like `i` in `for(i <- List(1,2,3,4)) ...`

Comment: + 1 but you can simplify by leaving off the final `.toSeq` as it doesn't do anything useful

Comment: This doesn't correctly handle cases where a key is in one map but not the other, and rebuilding the map also makes it more expensive than `intersectionWith`, which is linear with the total number of elements.

Comment: "This doesn't correctly handle cases where a key is in one map but not the other." Doesn't it? I can't see how that fails. Agree with the second point though.

Answer (score 15):

Scalaz adds a method `|+|` for any type `A` for which a `Semigroup[A]` is available.

If you mapped your Maps so that each value was a single-element sequence, then you could use this quite simply:

```
scala> a.mapValues(Seq(_)) |+| b.mapValues(Seq(_))
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Seq[java.lang.String]] = Map(1 -> List(one, un), 2 -> List(two, deux), 3 -> List(three, trois))
```

Comment: Actually, my values in the real case are Sequences, but I want to combine them by building into another sequence, rather than by appending one to the other.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you, sorry - do you want the values to be nested sequences or not?

Comment: Yes, I would want nested sequences, which I could do by wrapping my existing sequences in a Seq, but this feels somewhat like cheating - and in other cases I might want to use a completely different combiner that wouldn't fit into the semigroup structure - giving the size of the intersection of the value sequences, for example.

Comment: I see, admittedly this is just a cheat that I would consider using in this particular situation, not a general solution.

Answer (score 4):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, you can use [`groupMap`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/Seq.html#groupMap[K,B](key:A=%3EK)(f:A=%3EB):scala.collection.immutable.Map[K,CC[B]]) which (as its name suggests) is an equivalent of a `groupBy` followed by `map` on values:

```
// val map1 = Map(1 -> "one", 2 -> "two",  3 -> "three")
// val map2 = Map(1 -> "un",  2 -> "deux", 3 -> "trois")
(map1.toSeq ++ map2).groupMap(_._1)(_._2)
// Map(1 -> List("one", "un"), 2 -> List("two", "deux"), 3 -> List("three", "trois"))
```

This:

- Concatenates the two maps as a sequence of tuples (`List((1, "one"), (2, "two"), (3, "three"))`). For conciseness, `map2` is *implicitly* converted to `Seq` to align with `map1.toSeq`'s type - but you could choose to make it explicit by using `map2.toSeq`.
- `group`s elements based on their first tuple part (`_._1`) (group part of **group**Map)
- `map`s grouped values to their second tuple part (`_._2`) (map part of group**Map**)

Answer (score 3):

```
val fr = Map(1 -> "one", 2 -> "two", 3 -> "three")
val en = Map(1 -> "un", 2 -> "deux", 3 -> "trois")

def innerJoin[K, A, B](m1: Map[K, A], m2: Map[K, B]): Map[K, (A, B)] = {
  m1.flatMap{ case (k, a) => 
    m2.get(k).map(b => Map((k, (a, b)))).getOrElse(Map.empty[K, (A, B)])
  }
}

innerJoin(fr, en) // Map(1 -> ("one", "un"), 2 -> ("two", "deux"), 3 -> ("three", "trois")): Map[Int, (String, String)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my first approach before looking for the other solutions:

```
for (x <- a) yield 
  x._1 -> Seq (a.get (x._1), b.get (x._1)).flatten
```

To avoid elements which happen to exist only in a or b, a filter is handy:

```
(for (x <- a) yield 
  x._1 -> Seq (a.get (x._1), b.get (x._1)).flatten).filter (_._2.size == 2)
```

Flatten is needed, because b.get (x._1) returns an Option. To make flatten work, the first element has to be an option too, so we can't just use x._2 here.

For sequences, it works too:

```
scala> val b = Map (1 -> Seq(1, 11, 111), 2 -> Seq(2, 22), 3 -> Seq(33, 333), 5 -> Seq(55, 5, 5555))
b: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Seq[Int]] = Map(1 -> List(1, 11, 111), 2 -> List(2, 22), 3 -> List(33, 333), 5 -> List(55, 5, 5555))

scala> val a = Map (1 -> Seq(1, 101), 2 -> Seq(2, 212, 222), 3 -> Seq (3, 3443), 4 -> (44, 4, 41214))
a: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,ScalaObject with Equals] = Map(1 -> List(1, 101), 2 -> List(2, 212, 222), 3 -> List(3, 3443), 4 -> (44,4,41214))

scala> (for (x <- a) yield x._1 -> Seq (a.get (x._1), b.get (x._1)).flatten).filter (_._2.size == 2) 
res85: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Seq[ScalaObject with Equals]] = Map(1 -> List(List(1, 101), List(1, 11, 111)), 2 -> List(List(2, 212, 222), List(2, 22)), 3 -> List(List(3, 3443), List(33, 333)))
```

Answer (score 1):

So I wasn't quite happy with either solution (I want to build a new type, so semigroup doesn't really feel appropriate, and Infinity's solution seemed quite complex), so I've gone with this for the moment. I'd be happy to see it improved:

```
def merge[A,B,C](a : Map[A,B], b : Map[A,B])(c : (B,B) => C) = {
  for (
    key <- (a.keySet ++ b.keySet);
    aval <- a.get(key); bval <- b.get(key)
  ) yield c(aval, bval)
}
merge(a,b){Seq(_,_)}
```

I wanted the behaviour of returning nothing when a key wasn't present in either map (which differs from other solutions), but a way of specifying this would be nice.

Comment: You've implemented a hash join. You could write different methods for each type of join, like left outer, right outer, outer, and inner that would give you the behavior you needed in each circumstance.

Comment: Note that `IntMap`'s `intersectionWith` handles the case of a key only occurring in one map as you specify here.

Comment: A shorter more efficent alternative that does the same would be:
`def merge[A,B,C](a : Map[A,B], b : Map[A,B])(c : (B,B) => C) = {
  for((k,v1) <-a; v2 <- b.get(k)) yield (k, c(v1, v2))
}
merge(a,b){Seq(_,_)}`

Answer (score 0):

```
def merge[A,B,C,D](b : Map[A,B], c : Map[A,C])(d : (Option[B],Option[C]) => D): Map[A,D] = {
  (b.keySet ++ c.keySet).map(k => k -> d(b.get(k), c.get(k))).toMap
}

def optionSeqBiFunctionK[A]:(Option[A], Option[A]) => Seq[A] = _.toSeq ++ _.toSeq

merge(a,b)(optionSeqBiFunctionK)
```

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of just pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.