# Scala transform a list of maps into a map of lists

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have the following input:

```
List(
 Map("A" -> 1, "B" -> 2, "C" -> 3),
 Map("A" -> 4, "B" -> 5, "C" -> 6),
 Map("A" -> 7, "B" -> 8, "C" -> 9)
)
```

which I want to transform into:

```
Map(
 "A" -> List(1,4,7),
 "B" -> List(2,5,8),
 "C" -> List(3,6,9)
)
```

I have tried to use transpose but I'm not getting anywhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala: Merge maps by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755214/scala-merge-maps-by-key) (and several other questions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `flatten`, then `groupBy` and then `mapValues` to keep the list

```
list.flatten.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2))
```